# jersey helloworld with maven deployed on tomcat7

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I want to create jersey, maven, tomcat helloworld app. I followed [this tutorial](http://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/)  for maven, tomcat setting and [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) for helloworld app creating. My implementation can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58097953/RESTfulExample.zip), important files are below:

#### HelloWorldService.java

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

#### web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

#### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mkyong.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>RESTfulExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RESTfulExample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                 <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
        <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/RESTFulExample</path>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

#### index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

When I write: mvn tomcat7:deploy everything is OK and app is deployed. And Hello World on `localhost:8080/RESTFulExample/` is shown. But when I go to `localhost:8080/RESTFulExample`/rest/hello/something the exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
```

is throwed. Any idea where problem can be? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After looking through your project, the problem is with your directory structure

```
src/main/com/mkyong/rest
```

A Maven project has a [**strict** project structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

```
src/
    main/
        java/    <===== You are missing this
            com/mkyong/rest
```

So when you build the project, your `HelloService.java` file doesn't get compiled to the required .class file. In a Maven project, you can look in the `target/classes`, and in a webapp, in the `WEB-INF/classes`. This is where the `.class` files are compiled to. You can check there and you won't find anything.

So if you add the `java` directory in the correct location, and build the project again, you should see the `.class` files in the correct location, and the application should work.

- See [Maven Getting Started](http://maven.apache.org/users/index.html) to learn more about Maven

Comment: Perfect, I cant believe that I missed it, thank you very much.